# How can I recognize LLC, RAW and SNAP with Pcap.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I am trying to recognize LLC, RAW and SNAP type of packet in C#.
For Ethernet i have this code `if (packet.DataLink.Kind == DataLinkKind.Ethernet`
But I do not know how to recognize other (LLC,RAW,SNAP). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `IDataLink.Kind` property returns an Enum value for the datalink when it can translate it to one (otherwise it throws an exception).

The RAW datalink Kind is `DataLinkKind.IpV4`.

If the packet was received, you can probably down cast the `IDataLink` instance you have to `PcapDataLink` and use either the `PcapDataLink.Name` property or the `PcapDataLink.Value` property to get the string or integer value for the datalink.

If you have packets with datalinks that don't have a Kind value, you're welcome to provide .pcap samples for them in [Pcap.Net Q&A group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pcapdotnet) so I can add support for them.